# Magento 2 setup:di compile error In ErrorHandler.php line 61:

Tags: setup-di-compile

Warning: file_put_contents(root/generated/metadata/primary|global|plugin-list.php): failed to open s
tream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\wp7\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\PluginListGenerator.p
hp on line 414

Solved:
Go to -> vendor\magento\framework\Interception\PluginListGenerator.php

Find ->
`$cacheId = implode('|', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "|" . $this->cacheId;`

Replace ->
`$cacheId = implode('-', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "-" . $this->cacheId;`

Then run again setup:di:compile command line.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to -

> vendor\magento\framework\Interception\PluginListGenerator.php

Find ->

```
$cacheId = implode('|', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "|" . $this->cacheId;
```

Replace -> `$cacheId = implode('-', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "-" . $this->cacheId;`

Then run again setup:di:compile command line.

Answer (score 0):

thats not a better solution to change statement in vendor directory file so recommend any other solution because vendor is created by third party so its not a solution to change it on all modes on live instances